# Restriction of a surjective, continuous and open map to the inverse image of an irreducible component still open?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces which have only a finite number of irreducible components. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous, surjective and open map, such that for all $y\in Y$, $f^{-1}(y)$ is irreducible. Does $f$ induce a bijection between the sets of irreducible components of $X$ and $Y$?

(*) I think what I need to show the following: Let $Z\subset Y$ be an irreducible component. Then $f|_{f^{-1}(Z)}:f^{-1}(Z)\to Z$ is an open map.

The proof to my original question would then be as follows. If $Z\subset Y$ is an irreducible component, then the statement above implies that $f^{-1}(Z)$ is irreducible and since $Z$ is maximal, $f^{-1}(Z)$ has to be maximal and is hence an irreducible component. Vice versa, if $Z'\subset X$ is an irreducible component, then $f(Z')$ is irreducible and has to be maximal. If $f(Z')\subset Z$ for an irreducible component $Z\subset X$, then (*) would imply $f^{-1}(Z)$ is irreducible and $Z'\subset f^{-1}(Z)$.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to prove (*).

Comment: Thank you for the comment! But is the map you describe still open? A dense open subset of one irreducible component goes to a point, which is closed, but Y is connected. Maybe this is in fact what causes my confusion.

Comment: You are right! Let me think about this ;-)